# TF extrapolation into the past

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running several nodes on my robot involving some tf frames. I am following the tf tree structure suggested by the ROS navigation stack. Without going further into specific details, I would like to know if someone has encountered in the same situation I am.

I launch my nodes through a launch file. Some of these nodes use tf transforms without problems along the execution, until I occasionally got the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1319643007.826130513]: TF Error: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1319642992.659315000 but the earliest data is at time 1319642999.409401932, when looking up transform from frame [/robot/front_laser] to frame [/robot/odom]
```

As I said, this transforms have successfully been resolved many times, but suddenly it seems I am requesting for a transform before the tf listener received its first message.

I am using the waitForTransform on this form:

```
ros::Time request_time = ros::Time(0);
tf_exists = tf_listener_.waitForTransform(target_frame, pose.header.frame_id, request_time, ros::Duration(1));
```

Then if I get the transform:

```
if(tf_exists)
{
  geometry_msgs::PoseStamped out_pose;
  tf_listener_.transformPose(target_frame, request_time, pose, fixed_frame, out_pose);
}
```

Has anybody experienced this same error before?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11700/tf-extrapolation-into-the-past/) by [joan](https://answers.ros.org/users/881/joan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 245 on 2011-10-26

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error message states that you want to resolve a tf frame about 15 seconds in the past. By default, the [tf::TransformListener](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1TransformListener.html#a40d8462819c4e5280e8553080c4bd908) keeps only about 10 seconds of history.

Also, take a look at the [tf::MessageFilter](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Using%20Stamped%20datatypes%20with%20tf%3A%3AMessageFilter). It will do a lot of the annoying transform time synchronisation stuff, so you don't have to worry about it any more.

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2011-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0